# Checkboxlist with image struts2

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I'll try to put an image in my checkboxlist like this

```
<s:checkbox name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred1" id="chkAmex" />
<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/amex.png">
<s:checkbox name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred2" id="chkCmr" />
<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/cmr.png">
```

But i need to pass a list in one field to save it in my DB like
"true,false".

I'll try in this way

```
<s:checkboxlist id="chkTarjeta" name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred" 
        list="{
            '<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/amex.png">',
            '<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/cmr.png">'
                   }"

/>
```

but it doesn't work. HELP

Comment: Start to accept/upvote answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in the `<img/>` tags declaration: when you open the first **double quote**, you are closing the `list` attribute.

Put them in the Action (and read the values with a getter from the list attribute), or try escaping them manually;

```
<s:checkboxlist id="chkTarjeta" name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred" 
  list="{
    '<img alt=&quot;10&quot; src=&quot;./images/tarjetasCredito/amex.png&quot;>',
    '<img alt=&quot;10&quot; src=&quot;./images/tarjetasCredito/cmr.png&quot;>'
  }"
/>
```

I'm not sure if Struts2 will escape the values or not; if it will, the only chance would be to extend the Tag.

Answer (score 0):

To submit values in one string line use the same names on both checkboxes and your `evento.eve_tarjeta_cred` variable must be a String.
Use `<label>` tags to create labels of image for checkboxes.

**Note:** that unchecked chekboxes (`false` values) won't be submitted.

```
<label>
  <s:checkbox name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred" id="chkAmex" />
  <img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/amex.png" />
</label>

<label>
  <s:checkbox name="evento.eve_tarjeta_cred" id="chkCmr" />
  <img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/cmr.png" />
</label>
```

Comment: I solved it 2 days ago, just in each property NAME call(t1,t2,t3,...)
and in my "Action" class 
I

Comment: @JesusAlvarez: Two days ago? Answer is from Jul 12.

Comment: yes, I had other more important activities of another project.

Comment: @JesusAlvarez: You were busy it is understandable. But have you even tried this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this, in my JSP i got this

```
<s:checkbox name="t1" id="chkAmex" />
<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/amex.png">

<s:checkbox name="t2" id="chkCmr" />
<img alt="10" src="./images/tarjetasCredito/cmr.png">
```

and in my Action i declare a global variable "tarjetas", with get and set, obviously

```
tarjetas = t1 + "," + t2;
evento.setEve_tarjeta_cred(tarjetas);
eventoservice.RegistraEvento(evento);
```

and to show it in Update case, just do this

```
String[] tarjetasArray = evento.getEve_tarjeta_cred().split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < tarjetasArray.length; i++) {
                t1 = tarjetasArray[0];
                t2 = tarjetasArray[1];
            }
```

Comment: You don't have to have separate variables for each checkbox. Struts2 will put comma separated values in the string variable if you use the same names in JSP. See my answer, and w/o label tags your images are not clickable.